# Loading data from JSON files to a smart contract

Tags: solidity

I am new to solidity blockchain. I have transaction dataset in  JSON files. I want to load it automatically to blockchain using ethereum solidity in https://github.com/itzmeanjan/merklize-sha. How can I do it? Any guide would be helpful.

https://github.com/itzmeanjan/merklize-sha
https://easyupload.io/fhmezd

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's not recommended to use Etheruem as a storage for files, it will be very expensive.

1 kilobyte costs 640,000 gas to store, with a gas price of 15 Gwei and ETH price of $1,000 you'll pay $9.6 for 1 KB. The file you linked weights 10 MB so it'll cost around $10,000 to store it on the Ethereum blockchain.

If you want to do this anyway, you can just send a transaction with your file as input, no need to deploy a smart contract. Read [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-create-a-permanent-uncensorable-message-on-the-ethereum-blockchain-afd1ad23fa5e) post on "How to create a permanent uncensorable message on the Ethereum blockchain".